# How to retrieve data from firebase correctly?

Tags: javascript, firebase

It's been a while since Ive coded so sorry about my vocabulary. I can't seem to load the data I want. The Concole Log shows the values already of everything instead of the childs. So my database is the picture but console log just shows the numbers like 2,140,70,etc and childData.laps is undefined and `var averageBoardRef = database.ref('average_board');`

[image: Database Pic]

```
averageBoardRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        $('#average_laps-display').append(`
            ${childData.laps}
        `);
        console.log(childData)
    })
});
```

I want to be able to have childData.laps = 2 or if someone can tell me a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *either* loop over the child nodes *or* get the value of a specific, named child node. You code is mixing both, which means that neither of them works as you seem to want.

---

If you just want to get the value of the `laps` property, you can do:

```
averageBoardRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    $('#average_laps-display').append(snapshot.val().laps);
});
```

Alternatively, you can load less data if you do it like this:

```
averageBoardRef.child('laps').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    $('#average_laps-display').append(snapshot.val());
});
```

---

If you want to loop over all properties, and do something with their values, that'd be:

```
averageBoardRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData); // prints 140, then 2, then 2, then 4, etc
    })
});
```